# Passing an extjs object variable to javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, object, extjs4

I'm using ExtJs 4.0.
I have a *record* object having 5 fields.

- type -> string
- name -> string
- formFields -> 1D array
- gridColumns -> 1D array
- gridStore -> 2D array

Also, I have an anchor tag as

```
{
        xtype: 'component',
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'a',
            **href: 'javascript: addFormTab('+record+')',**
            html: record.name,
            style: 'position:absolute;left:'+left+';top:'+top
        }
}
```

I want to pass that *record* object variable to the *addFormTab* function.
But whenever I pass the variable, it is converted into string as *"[object Object]"* and gives javascript error.

Please suggest some way to pass the whole object, so that I can access it like

```
function addFormTab(record){
var form = new Ext.FormPanel({
    title: record.name,
    items: record.formFields,
});
}
```

Comment: Do not get what you mean about "pass the variable". Where the record is created? Is it a config in some container or some store? Could you explain clearer or post more code?

Comment: 'record' is not a config or store, just an object on 5 fields. eg 'record.name' will give the name and so on. But when you alert such objects as alert(record), it will give alert [object Object] after converting into string. The same thing is happening while passing it into that function. Hope you got it.